# How data initialization works?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, initialization, sql-server-ce, seeding

I have problem with initializing data into SQL Server Compact `.sdf` data file in .NET web application.

I have a data initialization class.

```
namespace R10491.Models
{
    public class SampleData : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<LibraryEntities>
    {
        protected override void Seed(LibraryEntities context)
        {
            var categories = new List<Category>
            {
                new Category{Id=1, Name="Sci-fi"}
            };

        }
    }
}
```

(for testing purposes I use `DropCreateDatabaseAlways` instead of `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges`)

This initializer class I call in the `Global.asax.cs` file:

```
protected void Session_Start()
{
   System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new R10491.Models.SampleData());
}
```

(again for testing purposes I call it on every session start).

My connection string definition:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="LibraryEntities"
     connectionString="Data Source=C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\2OBOP3_KU1\R10491\App_Data\R10491_library.sdf;"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

But the initialization doesn't work - tables defined in `SampleData` class are not created nor data are initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're forgetting to add the just created `Category` to the DB table. If you don't add it to the `context`'s table, `Entity Framework` won't see anything... So you must do something like this:

```
protected override void Seed(LibraryEntities context)
{
    var categories = new List<Category>
    {
        new Category{Id=1, Name="Sci-fi"}
    };

    foreach(Category c in categories)
    {
        context.Categories.Add(c)
    }

    // Call the Save method in the Context
    context.SaveChanges();  
}
```

---

For the DataSource problem, try this modified connection string:

```
<add name="LibraryEntities"
     connectionString="DataSource=|DataDirectory|R10491_library.sdf"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
```

In one of my projects I have this connection string:

```
<add name="FitnessCenterContext"
     connectionString="DataSource=|DataDirectory|FitnessCenter.Model.FitnessCenterContext.sdf"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
```

Note above that the database name matches the namespace and Context name.

---

I also use `Application_Start()` to call the `SetInitializer` method in `Global.asax.cs` file. I see that you're calling it inside `Session_Start()`. Maybe this is the problem... Change your code to:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
     System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new R10491.Models.SampleData());
}
```

---

You can also try calling the `Initialize` method:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
     System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new R10491.Models.SampleData());

     using (var context = new LibraryEntities())
     {
         context.Database.Initialize(true);
     }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I missed it, thanks. But there is one another problem. When I delete a .sdf file and run an my application the .sdf data file is not created and should be, isn't it? It is connected to my original question how this initalization process works.

Comment: Yes... it should be created automatically after you restart the app and it detects the `.sdf` doesn't exist anymore. Generally this file is created within the `\App_Data` folder.

Comment: But in my case the `.sdf` file is not created. Is there some necessity to commit changes or somethink like it? Where should be problem? Thanks for any advice, I googled for one hour and I have no idea where is problem. Maybe is a problem with my ConnectionString - I defined file location as full path (many tutorials use another syntax).

Comment: I mentioned connection string in my question above.

Comment: I tested connection string modification and `.sdf` file is not created. What did you mean "Note above that the database name matches the namespace and Context name"? In my case connection string `<add name="LibraryEntities" connectionString="DataSource=|DataDirectory|LibraryEntities.sdf;" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>` - database file name and context name is the same. What did you mean with namespace?

Comment: One more information - when I refresh Data connections in Database explorer there is an error - `The database file cannot be found. Check the path to the database. [ Data Source = C:\Users\Administrator\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\2OBOP3_KU1\R10491\App_DataLibraryEntities.sdf ]`. Note there is missing directory separator between App_Data directory and database file. Maybe this is the cause?

Comment: My context class `FitnessCenterContext` is inside the namespace `FitnessCenter.Model`. It's a separate class library that I use. If you're not familiar with namespace, check this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0d941h9d.aspx. Can you please tell me what you're using: SQL Server Express, LocalDB, etc... to store the data. Did you try placing the code inside `Application_Start()` instead of `Session_Start()`?

Comment: I want to use SQL CE and .sdf file as is used in this tutorial - http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-1 I use (as I mentioned in my original question for testing purposes) Session_Start() because Application_Start() didn't work as well and Session_Start() is called every time application is started.

Comment: Btw. - the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852373/mvc3-tutorial-connection-string

Comment: Did you place a breakpoint in the code and saw if it's being executed not throwing an exception? Did you check the App_Data folder? What version of Visual Studio are you using? This tutorial is somewhat old and things may not work as expected anymore (just a thought).

Comment: Hello Leniel. Problem was (most likely) in connection string mentioned in tutorial. There were missing directory separator between `|DataDirectory|` and the data file. But probably there were mismatch with installed versions too. I reinstalled OS and now it works. Thank for your patience.