# MvcMusicStore database connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am following the asp.net MvcMusicStore tutorial and everything works fine but the data is not adding to MvcMusicStore.sdf...This is the page with that part of the tutorial that makes the connection to database: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-4
The expected result should return a list with all of genres, but in my case I'm getting NULL values in MvcMusicStore.sdf Genres table.

I downloaded the completed tutorial and everything works fine there, all data values are inserted to database tables..

SampleData.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MvcMusicStore.Models
{
    public class SampleData : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MusicStoreEntities>
    {
        protected override void Seed(MusicStoreEntities context)
        {
            var genres = new List<Genre>
            {
                new Genre { Name = "Rock" },
                new Genre { Name = "Jazz" },
                new Genre { Name = "Metal" }
            };

            var artists = new List<Artist>
            {
                new Artist { Name = "Aaron Copland & London Symphony Orchestra" },
                new Artist { Name = "Aaron Goldberg" }
            };

            new List<Album>
            {
                new Album { Title = "A Copland Celebration, Vol. I", Genre = genres.Single(g => g.Name == "Classical"), Price = 8.99M, Artist = artists.Single(a => a.Name == "Aaron Copland & London Symphony Orchestra"), AlbumArtUrl = "/Content/Images/placeholder.gif" },
            }.ForEach(a => context.Albums.Add(a));
        }
    }
}
```

Web.config:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MusicStoreEntities"
     connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|MvcMusicStore.sdf"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(
        new MvcMusicStore.Models.SampleData());
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

Genre.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MvcMusicStore.Models
{
    public partial class Genre
    {
        public int GenreId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public List<Album> Albums { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you maybe post your model of genre-class?

Comment: `DataDirectory` did u replaced this?

Comment: @MatthiasBurger I've updated the code with the genre class

Answer (score 0):

You are not effectively adding the genres and artists to the database.

The line `context.Albums.Add(a)` adds the albums to the context but the equivalent calls for genres and artists are missing.
The following lines should be added:

- `context.Artists.AddRange(artists)`
- `context.Genres.AddRange(genres)`

Comment: I have added these lines of code, but now I'm getting the following error on AddRange: 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<MvcMusicStore.Models.Genre>' does not contain a definition for 'AddRange' and no extension method 'AddRange' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<MvcMusicStore.Models.Genre>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Where have you added the code?
As you can see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.addrange(v=vs.113).aspx) the methods are supported on DbSet type.
Maybe you are missing some namespace or references.